# Presto (Athena) loading of a CSV file with quote-escaped commas

Tags: csv, amazon-athena, presto

Consider the following row in a CSV file:

```
1,0,True,"{""foo"":null,""bar"":null}",0,1
                       ▲
```

The highlighted `,`  is **part of a column**. That is, this full text: `" {""foo"":null,""bar"":null}"` is the value of a single column. However AWS Athena is interpreting the highlighted `,` as a **column-delimiting comma**, incorrectly splitting that text into multiple columns.

I know I could change the column delimiter to something else to avoid this problem. My question is: Is this a bug in AWS Athena / Presto? How can I escape these commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is enclosed in double quotes, you need to use [OpenCSVSerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html) .

for the sample data, the following table definition works:

```
1,0,True,"{""foo"":null,""bar"":null}",0,1
```

How to escape comma inside the data

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `extra_comma`(
  `a` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `b` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `c` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `d` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `e` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `f` string COMMENT 'from deserializer'
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://aws-glue-stackoverflow/comma_in_data/'
```